ag-grid: sizeColumnsToFit not working as expected
I am running into an issue with the sizeColumnsToFit method on my grid.
The main issue is that when I have an empty column, and want it to be the minWidth value so that it takes up minimal space.  However, it doesn't set the width to that value when it is empty.  Instead it sets it much wider and then I just have these wide empty columns all throughout.  The grid is 12 columns and I have some data sets where 8/12 columns are empty and instead of making the other columns with data wider, it's nearly making them all the same width which just results in so much wasted empty white space.
I was trying different things and noticed if I call gridApi.autoSizeAllColumns() that it sizes the columns properly.  I then tried to immediately call gridApi.sizeColumnsToFit() hoping that would now resize everything to fit on my screen with the minimal width empty columns, but that is not how it works.
I dug down into the actual ag-grid code and it ended up being the column.resetActualWidth() being called on each column in the sizeColumnsToFit method.
I then messed around with the actual ag-grid code and if I remove that one line, it sizes everything exactly how I want it to - where all of the empty columns are the size they were set to when it autosized all the columns, which was the minWidth value I set - and then everything else is wider giving more use of the real estate.
There is just some weird stuff going on in there that will make the column larger than I want it to be if it is empty, dealing with the scale value that is set down in there, which in turn will then set the width to be larger than the width or initialWidth value that I give to the columns.
I am curious if anyone knows if there is a way to have it sizeColumnsToFit but will keep the empty columns at the minimum value you set.
Thanks.
